# What do the different aspects of Hindu gods mean?

Tags: hinduism

In Hinduism there are the main gods, and then each one has many aspects. What is an aspect? And what is it from a knowledge point of view? Is it a kind of relativity?

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site; questions about the philosophy of religion are on-topic, and questions regarding current practices/meaning for specific religions are generally off-topic unless you can prove that the topic has sufficient philosophical merit to be applicable. If you could expand on why you think philosophy has an answer to this question that would be more appropriate than a Hindu.SE site, that would be helpful for the readers.

Comment: what do you mean by relativity?

Comment: The Gods occupy a perceptive viewpoint of multiplicity compared to the traditional subject.

Comment: @AndrewWelch I can see a question in here that's worth working on, but you will have to do that first before you can count on good answers, and maybe it will get closed in the meanwhile. I would still encourage you to do that, many questions never get the attention they could have had because the edit never happens.

Comment: @stoicfury - IMO this question is relevant in that it addresses a problem that almost all of the major religions are faced with in one form or another. Therefore we must consider the possibility that this is not a question about any particular religion or practice, but a question about how humans perceive and describe some sort of higher power or intelligence. (see my comments on Mozibur Ullah's excellent answer)

Answer (score 2):

Hinduism should be considered a loose collection of religions who have certain family resemblances; rather than say something like Christianity which has a God, Jesus and the Bible in common despite the many theological differences between varying divisions.

There is a polytheistic side to Hinduism and a monotheistic side to it to - which is best displayed in the Upanishads, and was revived in Bengal as the [Brahmo Samaj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmo_Samaj) when India was under British rule - one could argue it was the imported Christianity that reawakened this idea in Bengal.

Brahman is described in the [Isha Upanishad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isha_Upanishad)

> unembodied, omniscient, beyond reproach, without veins, pure and uncontaminated..., [one who] moves and does not move...far away, but very near as well...although fixed in His abode is swifter than the mind...For the enlightened one all that exists is nothing but the Self

A certain position says that the gods themselves are simply a certain particularity of the universal Brahman; each god has many avatars. They are a material, and personal manifestation of the immaterial and impersonal Brahman.

Different philosophical schools explain Brahman differently. The gods & their avatars have a complex mythology and philosophy. One example will have to suffice:

Vishnu is the preserver; Shiva the destroyer and Brahma the creator. One may wish to consider the parallels between this and Hegels dialectical triad: thesis, anti-thesis and synthesis. His triad drives the world-mind. The Hindu triad does likewise for the world itself.

Comment: Excellent! I was going to answer by citing a parallel problem/pattern in Kabbalistic Judaism. But you have gone to Hindu theology itself, which is essentially identical to the explanation offered by the Kabbalists, particularly this segment: "Certain position says that the gods themselves are simply a certain particularity of the universal Brahman.... manifestation of the immaterial and impersonal Brahman." As we have discussed, early kabbalists were accused of paganism because they discussed different manifestations of God. Their teaching were misconstrued and interpreted as polytheism.

Comment: Among Jewish theologians there was/is serious disagreement about whether or not Christianity is polytheistic, because it is based on the Trinity concept - a similar conundrum....

Comment: @ReallyRational: I think there are disagreements within Christian theology itself. For example Unitarianism, the Arian heresy. I've wondered myself whether the trinity was the impact of roman polytheism on the early church; I'd be interested if anyone has investigated that angle.

Comment: 'I think there are disagreements..' - yes I am aware of that:Different ways of 'slicing and dicing it'. I know Unitarians consider themselves to be the true Christians, but I'm not if the rest of Christianity considers them Christian at all! "...the impact of roman polytheism on the early church" Indeed. I don't have any sources offhand but I'm sure someone has been there, and IMO it's quite plausable. It is clear that Roman Catholicism borrowed and adopted from Roman paganism to make themselves more 'marketable'. :-) I believe some of this is well documented historically.